# Stuck at the login screen syncing home share

Tags: macos, home-sharing

It’s stuck at the login screen syncing home share. I have confirmed that it’s connecting to the wireless network. The `beach ball` just keeps spinning. I’ve tried time machine-no backup, repair permissions and disk-no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange issues with this macbook. In the end bringing it up in `Safemode` once and then a `clean reboo`t allowed it to work. I didn’t even have to turn off `homesharing`